# Cannot create a new Azure Devops MSA account using my hotmail account. I have an AD Devops account linked to my organisation which works fine

Tags: azure, azure-devops, user-accounts

I have a work DevOps account in my organisation, but cannot create personal DevOps account. Am I not permitted a second DevOps environment for my personal use?

I am trying to create a second dev.azure.com account using my Microsoft Hotmail account and it keeps reverting to my work DevOps account event though I log in with Pretz.XXX@hotmail.com

I have an AD account Pretz.xyz@fabclothes.com which logs in fine to my Azure DevOps organisation environment

Each time I try creating a personal Azure DevOps account (at work), I keep getting redirected to the work Azure DevOps account.

Comment: You can try other browsers to see if the problem still exists.Is it be because of browser cache?

Comment: Have you tried going to dev.azure.com in a private/incognito window and logging in that way?